# How to structure an Angular2 + NodeJs + Express app using Typescript

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, angular

Now that angular2 is beta, I would like to start a new project using it together with node and express.
Are there some kind of best practices for the project's structure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They sure move fast - three releases in one day today.

I don't think there are any best practices yet as it just went beta.  However, I am seeing a number of people distributing on Firebase.  You can sign up for free.

Here are two resources that I think might be helpful (I believe they are both around alpha 46ish).

Building an Angular 2 application from the ground up by Andres Dominguez
https://youtu.be/aK3BWiK2Tek

Building apps with Firebase and Angular 2 - Sara Robinson
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD0xYicNcaY

Hope this helps.

Comment: Angular2 quick start application with Repository pattern and updated to RC5

https://github.com/moizKachwala/Angular2-expressjs-mongoose-gulp-node-typescript